# How to use graphics class to write onto a text file in c#

Tags: c#, text, graphics

I need to create a document dynamically through code and then print and save it onto a .doc file. So far I have managed to use the graphics class to print the document but I have no idea how to get it to save the file in .doc or any text format for that matter. Is it possible to do this? If yes how can it be done?

Comment: I don't know about .doc creation, but my instincts tell me that using a graphics class for saving a file onto the disk is horribly wrong :S

Comment: If you are referring to [`System.Drawing.Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx), this is not possible. The purpose of that class is drawing (creating graphics) on a drawing surface (a canvas), be it an on-screen region, a bitmap image, or a virtual page model (that can be handed over to a printer). It is *not* intended to bring any contents into text files of any sorts, because text files (including doc files) do not have any drawing surface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but if you want to save what you produce with Graphics on disk, you could use windows metafiles (wmf). If `g` is your instance of `Graphics`, something like this:

```
        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
        Metafile curMetafile = new Metafile(@"c:\tmp\newFile.wmf", hdc);
        Graphics mfG = Graphics.FromImage(curMetafile);
        mfG.DrawString("foo", new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, 10));
        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        mfG.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't really mean you want to save graphics as text, and just want to create a Word document then you need to look at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

i.e. from [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Open a doc file.
    Application application = new Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // Write the word.
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
    }
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
    }
}
```